# youTube wont display in landscape on iPad version of application (iPhone is fine with same code)

Tags: iphone, ipad, youtube, orientation, landscape

I have a iphone app published and working for 1 year. I decided to rebuild as native iPhone / iPad version. It uses tabs and one tab contains a list of company youTube videos which when selected can be made to play full screen in landscape mode. Though this works fine in the iPhone version behaviour (same code) on the iPad is different - plays initially in tiny window which can be maximised but wont play in landscape mode. Note youTubeIdentifier passes in the video id. Pulled my hair out and searched high and low but cant see why it's different on the iPad. main code below, any tips very much appreciated. ... Keith

```
UIWebView * webView;

- (void) initUIWebView
{
     webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 320)];//init and create the UIWebView
     webView.delegate = self;    
     webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
     webView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | 
     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
} 

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    connectionWasChecked = NO;

    [self initUIWebView];
    [[self view] addSubview:webView];   

    lastConnectionType = iNetStat; // save current type  
    [self showVideo];
    return;
}

-(void) showVideo  
{   
    if(iNetStat == 1) // Only allow on WiFi cnnection
    {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

        htmlString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<object ><param name=\"movie\" "
                       "value=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&%@\"><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" "
                       "value=\"true\"><param name=\"allowScriptAccess\" value=\"always\"><embed "
                       "src=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&%@\"type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" "
                       "allowfullscreen=\"true\" allowScriptAccess=\"always\"></object>", youTubeIdentifier, youTubeIdentifier];

        strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&%@", youTubeIdentifier];

        [webView setHidden:NO];

        [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString: strURL]];  


    }
    else if(!connectionWasChecked)
    {       
        [webView setHidden:YES];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning - No WiFi available!" message:@"You need a WiFi connection to view this video."  
                                                        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
        [alert show];   
        connectionWasChecked = YES;

        return;      
    }
    lastConnectionType = iNetStat; // save current type
}

// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES; 
}
```